# TikZ - bug in \pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Can someone tell me if the following is a bug?  MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{onetwo}{onetwo}{triangle 45}{triangle 45}{open triangle 90}{open triangle 90}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*{twothree}{twothree}{open triangle 90}{open triangle 90}{triangle 45}{triangle 45}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*{onetwo three}{onetwo three}{onetwo}{onetwo}{triangle 45}{triangle 45}
\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine{one twothree}{one twothree}{triangle 45}{triangle 45}{twothree}{twothree}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-onetwo] (0,3) -- (2,3);
\draw[-twothree] (0,2) -- (2,2);
\draw[-onetwo three] (0,1) -- (2,1);
\draw[-one twothree] (0,0) -- (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The third and fourth combinations differ even though they are the same up to associativity.  In the fourth combination, a gap appears between the leftmost triangle and the middle (open) triangle.  I don't think this gap should be there.

I believe the problem is in the definition of the second combination, `twothree`, specifically that its "left extend" (cf. manual section 74.2 under "The left and right extend") is wrong.

According to the manual, `\pgfarrowsdeclarecombine*` should make the line end before the inner arrow tip, which in this case is `open triangle 90`.  So the left extend should be that of the inner tip.

AFAICT, in `pgfcorearrows.code.tex`, the left extend is stored in `\pgf@arrow@left@<name of arrow tip>`.  So I added the following code to the end of the above document:

```
\makeatletter
\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname pgf@arrow@left@open triangle 90\endcsname}\par
\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname pgf@arrow@left@triangle 45\endcsname}\par
\texttt{\expandafter\meaning\csname pgf@arrow@left@twothree\endcsname}\par
```

The result shows that the second and third lines are the same, i.e. the left extend of `twothree` is that of the outer tip, namely `triangle 45`.

Does it look like a genuine bug, and if so, has anyone run into/worked around it before?

Comment: If you use the `*` at the declaration of `one twothree` instead of when you declare `twothree` you’re in the clear here. (Declare the unstarred version only for the `one twothree` version and another one with star for the direct use.) The additional “left extend” throws the definition of `one twothree` out of balance. Long story short: Don’t combine a `*` arrow again.

Comment: Only the last two declarations needs to be starred. You are nesting the the starred declarations so associativity claim is not correct.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel:  Thanks, that seems to work.  However, I'm still confused about the intended semantics of the "left extend".  As I understand it, the starred command is supposed to put the origin at the inner tip, so why keep the left extend of the _outer_ tip?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Care for an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because since the question has been asked, PGF changed the handling of arrows and also combining arrows. With the new version of combining arrows, the question is outdated.